# Angular js dynamic select not binding to ngmodel

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am dynamically generating a select using ngrepeat from a $scope object and need to assign the default select option based on another value within the same $scope object:
Here is current code:

```
<select id="group" ng-model="data.group" convert-to-number>
    <option ng-repeat="item in data.groups" value="{{item.id}}">
        {{item.group}}
    </option>
</select>
{{data.group}}
```

Object in controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    group: 2,
    groups: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Group One'
    },{
        id:2,
        name: 'Group Two'
    },{
        id:3,
        name: 'Group Three'
    }]
}
```

convert-to-number is a directive that converts $scope values to numbers to match with the id of the select options and everything works if I create hard coded options.

Once I dynamically generate the options with ng-repeat, it shows the correct options from data.groups in the select, and shows the correct group id in {{data.group}}, however the select box is blank and I have to click to see the options and when I select one it then updates {{data.group}} to the selected value of the option.

As mentioned with hard coded options all code works and the correct option is selected by default based on the {{data.group}} value.

Why is data.group not selecting the option in these dynamic options when first initialised?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way AngularJS works is by using `ng-selected` within the `<option>` tag to confirm which option matches the model. The following example code would work:

```
<option ng-selected="data.group == item.id"> ... </option>
```